# Jenkins NodeJS plugin yarn issue

Tags: jenkins, yarnpkg

If I select "Install Automatically" using NodeJS plugin for jenkins, I can install yarn using global npm packages to install:

[image]

How to install yarn if I did not select "Install Automatically"? The "Global NPM Packages to install" went missing:

[image]